# Latest version of Xamarin Studio (v6.1 or v6.2) does not launch/show

Tags: xamarin-studio

I installed XamarinStudio-6.1.1.15-0.msi and the install went fine with a success message at the end. Now I'm trying to launch it from the Start Menu as well as right clicking a solution file (.sln) but XS does not show. I see the process in Task Manager (task name is XamarinStudio.exe *32).

I do have Visual Studio 2015 installed and had Xamarin Studio 4.1 previously installed and which I installed XS 6.1.1 over it.

I checked out the log files in "..\AppData\Local\XamarinStudio-6.0\Logs" and here's the content:

```
INFO [2016-12-21 20:54:40Z]: Starting Xamarin Studio 6.1.1 (build 15)
INFO [2016-12-21 20:54:40Z]: Running on Microsoft .NET 4.0.30319.42000
INFO [2016-12-21 20:54:40Z]: Operating System: Windows 6.1.7601.65536 (64-bit)
INFO [2016-12-21 20:54:40Z]: Found GTK# version 2.12.22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GTK# seems to be really old (2.12.22), you can get the latest installer here: http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-win

Comment: Upgrading to version 2.12.30 got it to work. Thank you.